# Was ist die weibliche Form von "Kauz" wie in "seltsamer Kauz"?

Tags: translation, gender, russian-to-german

Ich versuche einen Ausdruck, der wortwörtlich "rothaariges Wunder" bedeutet, sinngemäß zu übersetzen. Es soll eine liebevolle und zugleich ironische Umschreibung eines rothaarigen Mädchens sein. Das Wort "Wunder" zielt hier eher auf eine gewisse Exzentrizität ab, nicht aber auf eine Hochbegabung wie in "Wunderkind". Ich dachte, "rothaariger Kauz" wäre ganz treffend, jedoch passt das Geschlecht nicht, da es sich ja um ein Mädchen handelt. Kann man das irgendwie ins Feminine übertragen, oder kann man die maskuline Form verwenden und der Sinn ergibt sich aus dem Kontext? Vielleicht gibt es sogar eine noch treffendere Übersetzung?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es gibt keine weibliche Form von "Kauz". Ich schlage die Verwendung des Adjektivs "kauzig" vor. Also beispielsweise

> kauziger Rotschopf

Statt "kauzig" kann man auch "exzentrisch" oder "verschroben" sagen.

Comment: Rotschopf enthält ja nur die Information über die roten Haare, aber nicht über die Einstellung, die der Ich-Erzähler zu der Person hat, oder?

Comment: @Photon Stimmt. Ich habe meine Antwort überarbeitet.

Comment: Das ist eine super gute Idee, vielen Dank!

Comment: Oder eben "weiblicher Kauz", wenn das Geschlecht noch nicht geoffenbart wurde. Man kann ja auch Männer als "Schlange" charakterisieren.

Comment: Millionen Frauen lassen sich täglich als "der Schatz" titulieren....

Answer (score 2):

Man könnte (vor allem, wenn es sich um ein Mädchen handelt)

> rothariges Käuzchen

verwenden. Ich persönlich hätte aber auch absolut kein Problem damit,

> rothaariger Kauz

zu schreiben.

Comment: Ah ja, das ist auch eine gute Idee, vielen Dank!

Answer (score 2):

Das grammatische und das biologische Geschlecht müssen im Deutschen nicht übereinstimmen.
Es ist also kein sprachlicher Fehler, eine Frau oder ein Mädchen als "komischen Kauz" zu bezeichnen.

Dasselbe gilt auch in umgekehrter Geschlechtsverteilung, zum Beispiel ist es durchaus gang und gäbe, auch Männer oder Jungen als "Schnecke" zu bezeichnen.

Lediglich bei Bezeichnungen, die ein bestimmtes biologisches Geschlecht implizieren, wie "Katze/Kater", "Stute/Hengst" oder "Gockel/Henne" würde eine falsche Zuordnung merkwürdig wirken. Selbst das kann von der poetischen Freiheit gedeckt sein, aber die meisten Muttersprachler versuchen das zu vermeiden, siehe z.B. die Wortbildung "gockelinnenhaft" in der Süddeutschen Zeitung vom 2.8.2022, S. 19.

Comment: Einen Mann/Jungen als "Schnecke" zu bezeichnen geschieht jedoch nicht in einem sexuellen Kontext wie bei Frauen, sondern ausschließlich als Verweis auf langsame Bearbeitungsgeschwindigkeit.

Comment: Auch bei Frauen wird die Bezeichnung "Schnecke" als Verweis auf Langsamkeit benutzt. Und auch in Kontexten, wo das Geschlecht der betreffenden Person nicht bekannt ist (z.B. Autoverkehr) impliziert die Bezeichnung kein (vermutetes) Geschlecht. Sie ist also in dieser Bedeutung vollständig geschlechtsneutral.

Comment: Das wird in meinem Kommentar nicht ausgeschlossen, lediglich nicht erwähnt.

Answer (score 0):

Je nachdem, was das "rothaarige Wunder" genau umfasst, könnte "Feuerkopf" eine Möglichkeit sein.

Comment: Nun, ich habe in der Eingangsfrage versucht, das ein wenig deutlich zu machen. Das Wort kann recht viele Bedeutungen haben. In Bezug auf Mensch könnte man das mit "Schatz" übersetzen ("Du bist ja ein Schatz!"), was Zuneigung und/oder Bewunderung ausdrückt, aber auch mit "lustiger Kauz" oder "Unikum", was eher Ironie und eine gewisse Exzentrizität der Person, die beschrieben wird, ausdrückt. Ich habe das Gefühl, dass hier ein wenig von beiden Bedeutungen drinsteckt.

Comment: @Photon Warum hast du bei "der Schatz" kein Problem, das auf ein Mädchen anzuwenden, bei "der Kauz" aber schon?

Comment: Ich weiß es nicht, bin kein Muttersprachler, deswegen wollte ich hier mal nachfragen. Die maskuline Form zu behalten, war ja eine mögliche Option (siehe meine Eingangsfrage), ich war mir bloß nicht sicher, ob sie so für das Sprachgefühl eines Muttersprachlers funktioniert.

Answer (score 0):

Kauzweibchen lautet die feminine Version, aber es ist in dieser Situation wahrscheinlich sehr unpassend, da es sich wohl eher nach Biologieunterricht anhört. :)
Wie wäre es denn mit: "verrücktes Huhn" – zusammen mit einer Anspielung auf die roten Haare. Ich kann dir die Seite https://www.dwds.de/wb/Kauz empfehlen! Meiner Meinung nach ist das die beste deutschsprachige Synonymquelle.

**Hier sind alle Synonyme, die ich bei DWDS gefunden habe:**

Freak · Mensch, wie man ihn nicht alle Tage trifft · Sonderling · Unikum · Wunderling · bizarre Person · merkwürdiger Zeitgenosse · schrille Person · seltsamer Patron · skurriler Typ · sonderbarer Zeitgenosse · uriger Typ · verrückte Person  ●  ungewöhnlicher Mensch  Hauptform · Kauz  ugs., fig. · Original  ugs. · Type  ugs. · Urvieh  ugs. · Vogel  ugs., fig. · bunter Vogel  ugs. · irrer Typ  ugs. · komischer Heiliger  ugs. · komischer Kauz  ugs. · komischer Vogel  ugs. · schrille Schraube  ugs., weibl. · schrille Type  ugs. · schräger Fürst  ugs., scherzhaft · schräger Typ  ugs. · schräger Vogel  ugs. · seltsame Type  ugs. · seltsamer Heiliger  ugs. · seltsamer Kauz  ugs. · verrücktes Huhn  ugs., weibl., fig.

**Edit:**
Eine kleine Kuriosität am Rande: Es gibt tatsächlich maskuline Wörter, die für weibliche Tiere verwendet werden. Da wäre zum Beispiel "der Rogner":

***https://www.dwds.de/wb/Rogner (Zoologie weiblicher, Eier enthaltender Fisch)***

Comment: Ich finde "verrücktes Huhn" klingt etwas zu grob, fast abfällig, während der Originalausdruck umgekehrt teils auch Zuneigung/Bewunderung transportiert (siehe dieses Kommentar: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71558/was-ist-die-weibliche-form-von-kauz-wie-in-seltsamer-kauz#comment171237_71562).

Comment: Das Wort "Kauzweibchen" habe ich noch nie gehört. Der Endung -chen nach ist es auch nicht feminin, sondern Neutrum.

Comment: Zu "verrücktes Huhn" -> Das ist auf jeden Fall eine Interpretationssache, jeder Muttersprachler wird es wahrscheinlich ein bisschen anders interpretieren. Es war nur ein Vorschlag von mir, aber letztendlich entscheidest du selbst ;)  "Mädchen" ist auch neutral, das haben alle Formen des Diminutivs im Deutschen gemeinsam.   Beispiel: Die Mutter -> das Mütterchen -> das Mütterlein -> das Mütterli -> das Mütterle  
Kauzweibchen: https://www.spiegel.de/wissenschaft/natur/untreue-eulen-wenn-das-futter-stimmt-machen-weibchen-die-fliege-a-608247.html